# Nodejs - Ajax delete method in using mongodb seems to work fine (no errors) but it's not working

Tags: node.js, ajax, mongodb, express, mongoose

Good day all!
I have an ajax method that sends data to the backend and the backend does operations with the data base (Rest API I think it's called).
The problem is, even thought I have no errors on frontend or backend, the operation I'm trying to complete doesn't take place. Hope you can help, thanks in advance.

```
//Front-end (jQuery ajax)


    $(document).on('click', '.remove-product', function () {
        //Get the ID variable inside the element we press
        var idEl = $(this).closest('.item-box');
        var id = idEl.find('.product-id').text();
        console.log(id);

        $.ajax({
            type:'DELETE',
            url: '/dashboard/:' + id,
            success: ajaxMessaging('green', 'Deleted a record')
        });
    });

//Backend
router.delete('/dashboard/:id', (req, res)=>{

    idStr = req.params.id;
    id = idStr.replace(":", "");    //Because : is sent through ajax
    console.log(id);

    User.deleteOne({_id : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}, (err)=>{
        if(err) console.log(err);

    });
});
```

Please note that I'm trying to delete an array index, but since every element has a unique id (right?) I'm trying to delete the index by id.

Comment: You should remove the `:` here `'/dashboard/:'`

Comment: What is logged for id?

Comment: the id from mongodb is logged into id

Comment: I removed : but it still doesnt give any errors or results

Comment: i mean remove `:` here. It should be `url: '/dashboard/' + id,`

Comment: And "not working" mean the record is still in db or something else?

Comment: Not working as in it removes item from db but app crashes. I fixed this I can't remember how though. Thanks for your help anyways!